# What is the difference between cache for web pages and cache for ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, caching

[This anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached/168973#168973) suggest "send 'no-cache' HTTP headers back with your response from the server." to work around ajax calls caching issues in IE.

With my limited knowledge, I assumed such a type of setting "no-cache" referred to grabbing a new page from the browser.

How is [ajax caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260458/why-doesnt-the-jquery-ajax-call-work-in-ie7-for-this-specific-example) tied to this functionality? One in the same? Differences?

Does no-caching in general just block a name value pair object from being sent to the server? - Which is the behavior I see when caching is enabled for an ajax call with the same previous name/values?

Comment: what i've found is that IE does not cache POST requests, which is why all my AJAX/JSON calls are POST. `.load` uses GET (AFAIK). Just a tip.

Comment: Well, I am using method: "post" in the jquery ajax call and it is caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With my limited knowledge, I assumed such a type of setting "no-cache" referred to grabbing a new page from the browser.

Yes, if a server sends the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header, it means that the browser must not use a cached copy of the page for future requests, i.e. it forces the browser to re-fetch the page every time.

> How is ajax caching tied to this functionality? One in the same? Differences?

There is no special cache for AJAX. It just happens that IE caches AJAX responses just like any other web page. Clearly, this leads to wrong results for multiple calls using the same URL.